# How to use JQuery dialog as Confirm dialog in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I am new to jquery and i am trying to open a dialog onclientclick of a button. The dialog is having some text and accept and decline button. On accept, it must do a server postback and and on decline should do nothing. Any pointers on this will be highly appreciated

I am trying to do the below.. but does not work

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

       $(function () {
           $("#SucessDialog").dialog({
               autoOpen: false,
               //width: 450,
               modal: true,
               resizable: false
           });
       });

function show_confirm()
{
       $("#SucessDialog").dialog('open');
}


<asp:Button ID="btnfinance" CssClass="btn green" runat="server" OnClientClick="show_confirm()" OnClick="btnfinance_click"  Text="Finance"  style="width:25%"></asp:Button>
```

Comment: What is it that doesn't work? (I would guess you first see the dialog, but the postback will happen right after that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JQuery

```
$('#SuccessDialog').
```

is a selector for an element with id: SuccessDialog.

Make sure you have a

```
<div id="SuccessDialog">some buttons</div>
```

on your page somewhere.

Having pointed out the basics, the show_confirm function doesn't cancel the postback instruction. You'll need something like:

```
OnClientClick="JavaScript: return show_confirm;"
```

and return false in your `show_confirm` function.

I think you can use an `<asp:button...` inside the JQuery dialog. Just make the confirm point to the postback thats in your Original button. If you got this working, you can try to improve the code to have a more general purpose.

Comment: No there is no popup opening and @stefan i have a div successdialog with buttons. Onclick of the button, there is just a post back happening and the popup/dialog is not opening.

Comment: The button event will not wait for jquery Dialog to return true or false.. it will just postback.

Comment: @kaushalparik27: OP's question is about opening the dialog. Besides; a blocking operation, i.e.; waiting for a dialog to return a value, is not a very good idea in javascript.

Comment: @Stefan that is what I said.